# Passing a variable to get_template_part

Tags: variables, get-template-part

The [WP Codex says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part#Passing_Variables_to_Template) to do this:

```
// You wish to make $my_var available to the template part at `content-part.php`
set_query_var( 'my_var', $my_var );
get_template_part( 'content', 'part' );
```

But how do I `echo $my_var` inside the template part? `get_query_var($my_var)` does not work for me.

I've seen tons of recommendations for using `locate_template` instead. Is that the best way to go?

Comment: Had [about the same question and got it to work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/270166/pass-a-variable-to-get-template-part) with `set_query_var` and `get_query_var`, however this was for using the values of an `$args` array that is passed to a `WP_Query`. Might be helpful for other people starting to learn this.

Comment: @Florian please see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/373230/54986 and mark as an answer if appropriate - it's now a first-class supported thing

Answer (score 73, accepted):

As posts get their data set up via `the_post()` (respectively via `setup_postdata()`) and are therefore accessible through the API (`get_the_ID()` for e.g.), let's assume that we are looping through a set of users (as [`setup_userdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/setup_userdata/) fills the global variables of the *currently logged in* user and isn't useful for this task) and try to display meta data per user:

```
<?php
get_header();

// etc.

// In the main template file
$users = new \WP_User_Query( [ ... ] );

foreach ( $users as $user )
{
    set_query_var( 'user_id', absint( $user->ID ) );
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/user', 'contact_methods' );
}
```

Then, in our `wpse-theme/template-parts/user-contact_methods.php` file, we need to access the users ID:

```
<?php
/** @var int $user_id */
$some_meta = get_the_author_meta( 'some_meta', $user_id );
var_dump( $some_meta );
```

That's it.

### Update (WP >= v5.5)

As pointed out in the comments, current versions of WP offer a *third* parameter for `get_template_part()`: `array $args`. So from this version on, you do not need to use `set_query_var( 'foo', 'bar' )` anymore. Example:

```
<?php
get_header();

// etc.

// In the main template file
$users = new \WP_User_Query( [ ... ] );

foreach ( $users as $user )
{
    $args = (array) $user;
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/user', 'contact_methods', $args );
}
```

Then, in our `wpse-theme/template-parts/user-contact_methods.php` file, we need to access the users ID:

```
<?php
/** @var array $args */
$some_meta = get_the_author_meta( 'some_meta', $args['ID'] );
var_dump( $some_meta );
```

---

The explanation is actually exactly above the part you quoted in your question:

> However, `load_template()`, which is called indirectly by `get_template_part()` extracts all of the `WP_Query` query variables, into the scope of the loaded template.

The native PHP [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.extract.php) function "extracts" the variables (the `global $wp_query->query_vars` property) and puts every part into its own variable which has exactly the same name as the key. In other words:

```
set_query_var( 'foo', 'bar' );

$GLOBALS['wp_query'] (object)
    -> query_vars (array)
        foo => bar (string 3)

extract( $wp_query->query_vars );

var_dump( $foo );
// Result:
(string 3) 'bar'
```

Comment: still working great

Comment: From WordPress 5.5 you can pass args to `get_template_part` function. Something like `get_template_part('somefile', null, ['arg1' => 'val1', 'arg2' => 'val2', ...]`.

Answer (score 28):

The `hm_get_template_part` function by [humanmade](https://github.com/humanmade/hm-core/blob/master/hm-core.functions.php) is extremely good at this and I use it all the time.

You call

```
hm_get_template_part( 'template_path', [ 'option' => 'value' ] );
```

and then inside your template, you use

```
$template_args['option'];
```

to return the value. It does caching and everything, though you can take that out if you like.

You can even return the rendered template as a string by passing `'return' => true` into the key/value array.

```
/**
 * Like get_template_part() put lets you pass args to the template file
 * Args are available in the tempalte as $template_args array
 * @param string filepart
 * @param mixed wp_args style argument list
 */
function hm_get_template_part( $file, $template_args = array(), $cache_args = array() ) {
    $template_args = wp_parse_args( $template_args );
    $cache_args = wp_parse_args( $cache_args );
    if ( $cache_args ) {
        foreach ( $template_args as $key => $value ) {
            if ( is_scalar( $value ) || is_array( $value ) ) {
                $cache_args[$key] = $value;
            } else if ( is_object( $value ) && method_exists( $value, 'get_id' ) ) {
                $cache_args[$key] = call_user_method( 'get_id', $value );
            }
        }
        if ( ( $cache = wp_cache_get( $file, serialize( $cache_args ) ) ) !== false ) {
            if ( ! empty( $template_args['return'] ) )
                return $cache;
            echo $cache;
            return;
        }
    }
    $file_handle = $file;
    do_action( 'start_operation', 'hm_template_part::' . $file_handle );
    if ( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file . '.php' ) )
        $file = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/' . $file . '.php';
    elseif ( file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/' . $file . '.php' ) )
        $file = get_template_directory() . '/' . $file . '.php';
    ob_start();
    $return = require( $file );
    $data = ob_get_clean();
    do_action( 'end_operation', 'hm_template_part::' . $file_handle );
    if ( $cache_args ) {
        wp_cache_set( $file, $data, serialize( $cache_args ), 3600 );
    }
    if ( ! empty( $template_args['return'] ) )
        if ( $return === false )
            return false;
        else
            return $data;
    echo $data;
}
```

Comment: Include 1300 lines of code(from github HM) to the project to pass one parameter to a template? Can not do this in my project :(

Comment: You can just include the code he pasted above to your functions.php...

Answer (score 24):

I was looking around and have found a variety of answers. Its seems at a native level, Wordpress does allow for variables to be accessed in Template parts. I did find that using the include coupled with locate_template did allow for variables scope to be accessible in the file.

```
include(locate_template('your-template-name.php'));
```

Comment: Using `include` won't pass [themecheck](https://github.com/anhskohbo/wp-cli-themecheck).

Comment: Do we really need something that is like the W3C checker for WP Themes?

Answer (score 10):

```
// you can use any value including objects.

set_query_var( 'var_name_to_be_used_later', 'Value to be retrieved later' );
//Basically set_query_var uses PHP extract() function  to do the magic.


then later in the template.
var_dump($var_name_to_be_used_later);
//will print "Value to be retrieved later"
```

I recommend to read about PHP Extract() function.

Answer (score 8):

## Update

As *selrond* correctly [answered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/373230/165265) as of **Wordpress 5.5** [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) ([see changelog](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/#changelog)) now accepts a **third parameter** `array $args = array()`, which will be available in your template file as `$args`.

### See this example:

```php
$bar = 'bar';

// get helper-my-template.php
get_template_part(
    'template-parts/helper',
    'my-template',
    array(
        'foo' => $bar, // passing this array possible since WP 5.5
    )
);
```

#### In your template file

e.g. **helper-my-template.php** you can now access your variable like this:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @var array $args
 */

$foo = $args['foo'];

?>

<h1><?php echo $foo; ?></h1>

<?php // will print 'bar' ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Starting in [5.5](https://make.wordpress.org/core/5-5/), it will be possible to pass data to templates via the various core template-loading functions.

All of the WordPress template-loading functions will support an additional parameter of `$args`, which allows theme authors to pass along an associative array of data to the loaded template. The functions that support this new parameter are:

```
get_header()
get_footer()
get_sidebar()
get_template_part()
locate_template()
load_template()
```

Any hooks associated with the functions also pass along the data.

For more information: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/

Comment: Unfortunately the `$args` parameter isn't run through `extract()` so you'll need to do `echo $args['foo']` in the template. I wish there was an option to extract the args too.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue on a project I'm currently working on. I decided to create my own small plugin that allows you to more explicitly pass variables to get_template_part by using a new function.

In case you might find it useful, here's the page for it on GitHub: https://github.com/JolekPress/Get-Template-Part-With-Variables

And here's an example of how it would work:

```
$variables = [
    'name' => 'John',
    'class' => 'featuredAuthor',
];

jpr_get_template_part_with_vars('author', 'info', $variables);


// In author-info.php:
echo "
<div class='$class'>
    <span>$name</span>
</div>
";

// Would output:
<div class='featuredAuthor'>
    <span>John</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$args` parameter for template loading functions has just landed in [WordPress 5.5 “Eckstine”](https://wordpress.org/news/2020/08/eckstine/):

> Passing data to template files
>
> The template loading functions (get_header(), get_template_part(), etc.) have a new $args argument. So now you can pass an entire array’s worth of data to those templates.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [Pods](http://pods.io/) plugin and their [pods_view](http://pods.io/docs/code/pods-view/) function. It works similar to the `hm_get_template_part` function mentioned in djb's answer. I use an additional function (`findTemplate` in the code below) to search for a template file in the current theme first, and if not found it returns the template with the same name in my plugin's `/templates` folder. This is a rough idea of how I'm using `pods_view` in my plugin:

```
/**
 * Helper function to find a template
 */
function findTemplate($filename) {
  // Look first in the theme folder
  $template = locate_template($filename);
  if (!$template) {
    // Otherwise, use the file in our plugin's /templates folder
    $template = dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/' . $filename;
  }
  return $template;
}

// Output the template 'template-name.php' from either the theme
// folder *or* our plugin's '/template' folder, passing two local
// variables to be available in the template file
pods_view(
  findTemplate('template-name.php'),
  array(
    'passed_variable' => $variable_to_pass,
    'another_variable' => $another_variable,
  )
);
```

`pods_view` also supports caching, but I didn't need that for my purposes. More information about the function arguments can be found in the Pods documentation pages. See the pages for [pods_view](http://pods.io/docs/code/pods-view/) and [Partial Page Caching and Smart Template Parts with Pods](http://pods.io/tutorials/partial-page-caching-smart-template-parts-pods/).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer from @djb using code from humanmade.

This is a lightweight version of get_template_part that can accept args. This way variables are scoped locally to that template. No need to have `global`, `get_query_var`, `set_query_var`.

```
/**
 * Like get_template_part() but lets you pass args to the template file
 * Args are available in the template as $args array.
 * Args can be passed in as url parameters, e.g 'key1=value1&key2=value2'.
 * Args can be passed in as an array, e.g. ['key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2']
 * Filepath is available in the template as $file string.
 * @param string      $slug The slug name for the generic template.
 * @param string|null $name The name of the specialized template.
 * @param array       $args The arguments passed to the template
 */

function _get_template_part( $slug, $name = null, $args = array() ) {
    if ( isset( $name ) && $name !== 'none' ) $slug = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";
    else $slug = "{$slug}.php";
    $dir = get_template_directory();
    $file = "{$dir}/{$slug}";

    ob_start();
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args );
    $slug = $dir = $name = null;
    require( $file );
    echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

---

For example in `cart.php` :

```
<? php _get_template_part( 'components/items/apple', null, ['color' => 'red']); ?>
```

In `apple.php` :

```
<p>The apple color is: <?php echo $args['color']; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
render( 'template-parts/header/header', 'desktop', 
    array( 'user_id' => 555, 'struct' => array( 'test' => array( 1,2 ) ) )
);
function render ( $slug, $name, $arguments ) {

    if ( $arguments ) {
        foreach ( $arguments as $key => $value ) {
                ${$key} = $value;
        }
    }

$name = (string) $name;
if ( '' !== $name ) {
    $templates = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";
    } else {
        $templates = "{$slug}.php";
    }

    $path = get_template_directory() . '/' . $templates;
    if ( file_exists( $path ) ) {
        ob_start();
        require( $path);
        ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

By using `${$key}` you can add the variables into the current function scope.
Works for me, quick and easy and its not leaking or stored into the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

For ones who looks very easy way to pass variables, you can change function to include:

> include( locate_template( 'YourTemplate.php', false, false ) );

And then you will be able to use all variables which are defined before you are including template without PASSING additionally each one for the template.

Credits goes to:
https://mekshq.com/passing-variables-via-get_template_part-wordpress/

Answer (score -3):

This is exact solution and it worked well.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_query_var/

Comment: I think you've misunderstood