# What can I use for small text when converting to Wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, templates

FYI before you mark it as duplicate: I found some similar questions, but they are from like 4 years ago and WP is constantly evolving.

For repetitive chunks like this I used posts to convert an HTML theme into WP:

```
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
       <div class="testimonails-content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah </p>
       <h6>Title <a href="#">Customer</a></h6>
       </div>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

What can I use for small unique pieces of text like this:

```
<div class="heading-section">
   <h2>A small heading</h2>
      <img src="" alt="" >
</div>
```

Is using posts ok, or there is a more or less standard way for it?

Comment: Chances are the old posts are still accurate in principle.

Comment: why don't you try `get_template_part`

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there are roughly two approaches to this:

1 Use [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). This is the normal way of inserting pieces of code into a template. However, you cannot pass arguments to this function. So if you want to repeat ten pieces of code with small variations, you cannot tell `get_template_part` what the variations are. It is possible to get around this: [Passing a variable to get_template_part](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part)

2 [Use an action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/). This will allow you to pass a variable to a function that generates a piece of html. In your theme you would have `do_action('my_hook',$args)`, while in your functions file you would define `add_action ('my_hook','my_hook_action');`. This may be more practical, but slightly less standard.