# using get_template_part() inside a widget and passing variables

Tags: widgets, get-template-part

I read that `get_template_part()` should only used by themes not plugins, I don't know if using it inside a widget function (created by the theme) is considered as a plugin or not.

Anyway, I'm trying to pass that widget variables ($myvar) to the template ('loop.php' in my case), but it doesn't fetch it even with using `global $myvar;` inside the template.

Here's my widget function code:

```
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    echo $before_widget;
    if ($title) { echo $before_title.$title.$after_title; }
    $myvar = 'start';
    get_template_part('loop'); ?>
    echo $after_widget;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, `get_template_part` is meant to be used in themes only, though that would include widgets inside your theme. [Looking at the source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) of the function you'll see that the main reason for this is that `get_template_part` does some extra theme related stuff before it calls `locate_template` in a non-default way.

That said you should have no problem calling it from a widget, so the issue most likely is that your `loop.php` is not in the place where WP is looking for it.

[Refer to this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part?rq=1) for passing a variable to a template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_query_var('myvarname', $myvarvalue);` before `get_template_part()`. Then in your loop template you can access the var using `$myvarname`.

You can also skip all that and use [locate template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) instead.

Comment: Doesn't work even outside the widget (in archive.php, for example).