# Can I add generic numbering HTML classes to items as a loop runs?

Tags: loop, css, html

When the a loop runs can I have each new post it grabs its own HTML class?

#### For example

- Loop runs
- First item gets `class="first"`
- Second item gets `class="second"`
- and so on...

Or each post just gets an equivalent numbered `class=` 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

I've just been using CSS with `nth-child()` to target each new item.

**index.php** (here's the loop call and get_template_part pulls content.php with the loop contents)

```

```
      <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>5, 'paged'=>$paged) ); ?> 

      <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

      <?php $counter = 1; ?>

      <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

      <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

```

**content.php** ( Here's the contents start of the loop where I want to add the class )

```

```
      <?php include(locate_template('index.php')); ?>

      <?php $counter++; ?>

      <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'inline-post-' . $counter ); ?>>
```

```

Comment: Maybe this will help - [a Simple class to convert number to words in php based on](https://gist.github.com/bainternet/5756049). Explain your task, maybe there is another, more clear solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`post_class`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class)  within the loop.

`<?php post_class( 'myclass-here'); ?>`

This will add the necessary HTML `class=""` and WP defaults classes plus your new `myclass-here` class

You could then use counters within the loop to add a unique suffix to your post class

```
// Outside the loop initialize your counter
$counter = 1;
```

.

```
// Then in the loop
<?php post_class( 'myclass-here-' . $counter ); $counter++; ?>
```

**EDIT**

Ok taking into consideration the new information in your question, the way to go is to [set a query var](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_query_var) and that variable would now be available in your template part.

**index.php**

Here you would set your query var just before calling `get_template_part()` and you would increment it just after. You still have to initialize outside the loop the `$counter` of course. it would look something like this

```
<?php set_query_var( 'counter', $counter ); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); $counter++; ?>
```

then in your **content.php** file, you would just have to call your variable `$counter`

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'inline-post-' . $counter ); ?>>
```

don't increment your `$counter` in your **content.php** file and don't include `locate_template()` either

Comment: post_class() is what I need, but I hit a few snags. For one this example needs an incrementor or all post will be myclass-here-1 also the loop is in get_template_part, and I can pass it a variable with include(locate_template()) except the counter needs to be outside the loop and include(locate_template('index.php') wont work. I guess index.php isn't a template

Comment: You could add a custom filter inside your template file and call the filter before calling `get_template_part()`, and incrementing `$counter` just after.  If you update your question by posting some code, it will be easier to help you out.  Also, why do you want to have a class name with an incremented suffix? couldn't you just use the `$post_id` as a way of differentiating each class. Better yet, using the post's HTML `id` tag is the best way to target each post individually.  Or maybe you need to know in a predictable way each class beforehand?

Comment: I've added a couple snippets of code. Maybe it will be clearer. Let's say I have a page with ten posts on it. The third post id will be forever changing when new posts are created. If I want to target the third post in the css  there's currently no way but with nth-child(3) make sense? @bynicolas

Comment: ok, I've edited my answer. you have to set a query var which will be available in your template part. The explanation is [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176807/99217)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```
if ( have_posts() ) :
    $post_count = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $post_count++;
    $post_classes = 'post-' . $post_count;
    ?>
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $post_classes ); ?>>
    <!-- post stuff here.... -->
    </article>
    <?php
    endwhile();
endif;
```

Comment: Looks promising. Let's say this is in my index.php file but the loop contents are in content.php. I can't seem to use include(locate_template('index.php'));  in content.php to use post_class($post_classes); there. The variables set in index.php won't get carried through to content.php . Too complicated to understand?