# How do I make a variable available inside partials?

Tags: loop, pages, templates, users, get-template-part

I've got a partial called within `single.php` that looks like this:

```
<?php   $userdata = get_userdata($post->post_author) ;  ?>  
<div class="entry-meta"> 
    <span class="byline author vcard"><?= __('By', 'sage'); ?>
    <a href="<?= get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>" rel="author" class="fn">
        <?php  echo ucfirst($userdata->user_nicename)  ?>
    </a>
    </span>    
</div>
```

Now, `$userdata` might be useful elsewhere within my single. So I'd like the variable and its value to be available globally within all templates that are included whenever my single is used.

So I cut out the first line: the creation of `$userdata` and put earlier in a 'parent' template that gets called earlier in the loop.

Alas, the variable was no longer avaiable to the partial. I tried a few other templates that are also called earlier in the loop. I got the same result: the variable wasn't available.

I thought about creating a function within `functions.php`. But I can think of a couple of reasons not to do this. First of all, why bother with an abstraction for `get_userdata()` when `get_userdata` already exists? This seems inelegant.

Comment: WP caches the user information. There's really no problem just to call `get_userdata` every time you need it. The only thing you are doing by transfering it to a variable `$userdata` is have WP fetch it from another place in the memory.

Comment: @cjbj as an answer please :)

Comment: @Rarst Yessir! Done sir!

Answer (score 4):

WordPress caches the user information. There's really no problem just to call `get_userdata` every time you need it. The only thing you are doing by transfering it to a variable `$userdata` is have WP fetch it from another place in the memory.

Note: read [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part) for a more general dealing with passing variables to partials.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two solutions:**

**1)** Use a variable like this
global `$userdata`;

```
$userdata = //object you want inside partial;
```

and then use

`global $userdata;` inside that `single.php` or loop etc.

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

**2)** Keep doing the things as you are except one change
instead of `get_template_part`
use `include_once('filename.php')`

Comment: Both are ways to circumvent WP's preferred way of doing this. Possible, but not recommended.

Comment: What is recommended then? Please share so we can learn something better.

Comment: See my comment under the question. There is no problem here. Also read [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part/176807#176807)