# Passing variables to template parts

Tags: templates, variables, include, get-template-part, globals

I have one template file `videos.php` which has the following line of code in it (aswell as a load of HTML):

`<?php get_template_part('loop', 'feed-videos' ); ?>`

inside that template part, I have the following:

```
<?php $video = 'video-' . $post->ID; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'include', 'modal-video' ); ?>
```

I would then like to be able to use the `$video` variable inside `include-modal-video.php`.

So at the top of `include-modal-video.php` I have:

```
<?php global $video; ?>
```

Further down that file, I have `<h2>00: <?php echo $video; ?></h2>`

But I get nothing output from that line of code. All I see is the following indicator of where the value *should* be

> 00

Can anyone see what Im doing wrong?

Comment: This might help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part

Comment: don't don't don't don't ever use globals

Comment: What's stopping you from requesting the `$post->ID` from inside that template part?

Comment: And to expand on my previous comment,, template parts are supposed to be independent  containers. If you need to pass global they are not independent any more, therefor if you feel like you need to pass a global you most probably doing something wrong

Comment: @MarkKaplun I had a feeling using globals were bad, but I swear I've read loads of other answers in the past that suggest using them? I'll steer clear of them anyway! ;)

Comment: @socki03 wow I hadn't actually thought of trying that as I thought I wouldn't be able to access the `$post` variable from inside there, but it worked! thanks

Comment: `$post` is just about the only global variable you need :)

Comment: @pealo86, yes and wordpress is full of globals which makes wordpress core code ugly to read and understand. Use them if there is no other way. In your case, you can have a filter "called" in your template part and set an handler in the "including" code. maybe I should make this into an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `locate_template()` instead of `get_template_part()` you can use all variables in that script:

```
include(locate_template('include-modal-video.php'));
```

Then, `<h2>00: <?php echo $video; ?></h2>` will work.

**UPDATE:**

Since WP version 5.5, you can pass arbitrary data to `get_template_part()` for use in the template - see the other answer below from @Denis Fedorov

Answer (score 3):

**Wordpress 5.5**

The **$args** parameter was added to `get_template_part` function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/#changelog

**Pass data**

```
$data = [
  'video' => 'video-' . $post->ID,
];
get_template_part('include', 'modal-video', $data);
```

**include-modal-video.php**

```
//handle passed arguments through $args
echo $args['video'];
```

**include-modal-video.php (extract)**

```
extract($args);
echo $video;
```

The possibility of passing additional arguments to the template was added to all the template functions that use `locate_template` in Wordpress 5.5:

`get_header`, `get_footer`, `get_sidebar`, `get_template_part`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sidebar/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/