# Detect if current page is front page within custom query

Tags: loop, frontpage, get-template-part

I am currently working on a project where we're designing a custom frontpage template for a static front page.

Within the template are three different custom WP_Queryies with relating loops. Within one of the custom loops, I use template-parts chosen by which post type the current post is. In these template parts (meaning within a custom loop), I would like to check if the current page (active page, meaning "frontpage" where the loop lives, not the current active element in the custom loop) is frontpage or search results page to display an icon for identifying different post types.

If my understanding of the descriptions of is_search and is_front_page is correct, these functions checks current element in loop, hence will they do me no good in this particular example.

An illustration is provided to assist the description above.

[image: Illustration: Checking if active page is frontpage or search in custom loops using site-wide template parts]

Does anyone have a good idea on how to check if the active page is the front page or the search results page in the custom loop?

Comment: You can do and save into a variable the check at the beginning of the template_frontpage.php file. Then you can do the check inside the loop. For example: Before all the loops `$isFrontPageOrSearch = is_search() || is_front_page()` and then inside loop `if(isFrontPageOrSearch)`

Comment: I like the idea, but the loop doesn't seem to reach the variable (not returning anything when echoed within the custom loop). I tried making the variable global, first in header to preserve scope, later in tpl_frontpage but with same result. Any thoughts on why this would occur?

Comment: At first I would put an integer or a string value at the variable and print it inside the custom loop. Not need for a global variable. That's because echoing `false` will print an empty string (nothing visible) and echoing `true` will print `1`. Better to use `var_dump($variable)` that will print `bool(false)` if the variable is false.

Comment: Tried both, unfortunately (both assigning the variable an actual integer based on an if-test, and using the boolean values). But as Stig-Ruben points out below, and a current google on get_template_part's scope indicates, we don't get to pass variables in to get_template_part. Thank you for the idea, anyhow :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understood that you want to pass a variable to another template / file. You want to do the check inside the template file ??

Comment: [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part) will help you pass the `$variable` to your template file.

Comment: is_front_page and is_search both check the global $wp_query and should work just fine inside a template part.

Comment: @Laxmana: Thanks, I'll check that solution out as well.

Comment: @Milo: The template part is used inside a loop of a custom WP_Query. I've even tried fetching global $wp_query inside the template without any luck.

Comment: get_template_part globalizes $wp_query via load_template function, so it should just work. I can't say why it doesn't for you without seeing your code.

Comment: @Milo But if you are on a page and then you make a custom WP_Query and inside your custom loop you call get_template_part, what is being globalized is your custom query and not the $wp_query of the initial page, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Marius, I have been in this situation before as well. Haven't found a good solution though. Answer provided by Laxmana won't work as the $isFrontPageOrSearch wont be accessible inside the template-part file. Although using the approach provided by Laxmana, you could be using PHP include(locate_template('your-template-name.php'));, instead of using get_template_part function. Then the variable would be accessible.

Comment: Cheers, Stig-Ruben. I was about to reach the same conclusion based on a google on get_template_part's scope, good to know it works! Then I'll implement this set instead.