# Pass a variable to get_template_part

Tags: get-template-part

In `category-about.php` I have

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the posts in the About category
 *
 */
?>
<!-- category-about.php -->
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'about',
  ); ?>

  <?php
  // How to put this part in get_template_part ?
  $cat_name = $args['category_name'];
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <section id="<?php echo $cat_name ?>-section">
    <h1 class="<?php echo $cat_name ?>-section-title">
      <strong><?php echo ucfirst($cat_name) ?> Section</strong>
    </h1><?php
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
      <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
        <div <?php post_class() ?> >
          <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div> <?php
        endwhile; ?>
  </section> <?php
  endif;
  wp_reset_query();
  // end get_template_part ?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

How can I have the variables from `category-about.php` in the template file `posts-loop.php`?

Looking at [this comment](http://keithdevon.com/passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/#comment-110459) and [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part) I have trouble putting it all together.

I would like to understand this better instead of using any of the helper functions provided in the answers. I understand that the correct way would be using `set_query_var` and `get_query_var` however I require a bit of assistance with that.

Instead of writing the core loop code for each category I like to just define the `$args` in the category template and then make use of that in the template file. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

In `category-about.php` I have

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the posts in the About category
 *
 */
?>
<!-- category-about.php -->
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'about',
  ); ?>

  <?php  
    // important bit
    set_query_var( 'query_category', $args );

    get_template_part('template-parts/posts', 'loop');
   ?>   
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and in template file `posts-loops.php` I now have

```
<!-- posts-loop.php -->
    <?php
    // important bit
    $args = get_query_var('query_category');

    $cat_name = $args['category_name'];
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if($query->have_posts()) : ?>
      <section id="<?php echo $cat_name ?>-section">
      <h1 class="<?php echo $cat_name ?>-section-title">
        <strong><?php echo ucfirst($cat_name) ?> Section</strong>
      </h1><?php
      while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <strong><?php the_title(); ?></strong>
          <div <?php post_class() ?> >
            <?php the_content(); ?>
          </div> <?php
          endwhile; ?>
    </section> <?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_query();
```

and it works.

Reference:
http://keithdevon.com/passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/#comment-110459
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176807/77054

Answer (score 1):

WordPress **5.5** allows passing `$args` to `get_template_part`. Apart from this function there are sets of template function which can now accept arguments.

```
get_header
get_footer
get_sidebar
get_template_part_{$slug}
get_template_part
```

Please refer more details at: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/17/passing-arguments-to-template-files-in-wordpress-5-5/

Answer (score 0):

**First way**:

*Template in which template part is included:*

```
$value_to_sent = true;
set_query_var( 'my_var', $value_to_sent );
```

*Included template part:*

```
$get_my_var = get_query_var('my_var');
if ($get_my_var == true) {
...
}
```

**Second way:**

*Template in which template part is included:*

```
global $my_var;
$my_var= true;
```

*Included template part:*

```
global $my_var;
if ($my_var == true) {
...
}
```

I would rather go with the first way.