# ACF - Theming Flexible Content

Tags: templates

I come from Drupal 8, where I am used to template files for each entity (piece of data). As far as I understood in WP every page template does look after it's own content via theming it via code that sits in the (page / post) tpl file itself.

I believe there must be a nicer way to theme an "ACF Flexible Field" than duplicating my template code into each page tpl the field maybe could be outputted in.

Can I define "one" tpl file that is used for every output instead?

Are there any Objects? Or inc's that I can create to deal with the field?
I understand that putting all the code into each page tpl makes it easy... but its also very static and it produces double code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And to add to previous answers, you can not only use `get_template_part`, but also use it's second param and combine it with ACFs `get_row_layout`.

So let's say that somewhere in your template is:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article>
    ... SOME CODE

    <?php while ( have_rows( 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME' ) ) : the_row(); ?>
    ... HERE SHOULD GO THE CODE FOR ACF FIELD
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    ... SOME OTHER CODE
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You can change it to:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<article>
    ... SOME CODE

    <?php
        while ( have_rows( 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME' ) ) :
            the_row();
            get_template_part( 'block', get_row_layout() );

        endwhile;
    ?>

    ... SOME OTHER CODE
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Then you can create your custom templates named: `block.php` (it will be used as fallback), `block-layout_1.php` (it will be used for layout called "layout_1", and so on.

Comment: fantastic answer. Exactly what I was after for. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can include template partials via [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). You can pass variables to template parts via [`set_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_query_var/).

Answer (score 1):

WordPress allows you to chop up template files into chunks that then can be included into the main template using [`get_template_part`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). So you could isolate your template for the ACF-field in a separate file and call that from any other template.

Beware that it is not directly possible to pass variables from the main template to the template part, though [there are bypasses](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part).